# SharePoint 2013 - Opening files while Web App is in Strict Mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file

My organization requires that SharePoint be in Strict mode for "Browser File Handling".  However, there are a few file types that are allowed to be open directly.

Is there a command that I can run to allow certain file types to be open directly from SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication("http://webAppUrl")
$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
$webApp.Update()
```